# URL to work with parameter and without parameter in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django for my project, and I want to render `thank-you` page.
But it should be with or without parameters.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path(r'thank-you?t=<type>?n=<name>', thank_you_view, name='thank-you'),
    ....
]
```

it is working fine for urls like :`http://127.0.0.1:8080/thank-you%3Ft=teacher%3Fn=Ajay,%20Gaikwad`
Template make use of parameters.

but not working for url without parameters like : `http://127.0.0.1:8080/thank-you`
Default template will be rendered here.

also I tried some regex

`path(r'thank-you(?t=<type>?n=<name>|'')', thank_you_view, name='thank-you'),` 
But it not working.

---

If you use below view and render context with template then it will work.

views.py

```
def thank_you_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {kwargs['type']: kwargs['name']}
    return render(request, "light/thank-you.html", context=context)
```

---

Edit:

- Is it any way to use regex in url so it will work for both ways?
- Or can we make parameters as optional?

Comment: Do you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Once you define path parameters, Django is expecting it in the URL. Else you can get it as query parameters. You're mixing up query and path parameters.